# How to display second zero when only single digit is returned after decimal, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I have two functions here...

```
function getCostOne() {
  var cost = 1.5;  
  return 1 * cost.toFixed(2);
}
```

**and...**

```
function getCostTwo() {
  var cost = 1.5;  
  return 1 + cost.toFixed(2);
}
```

What is the difference between multiplying `cost.toFixed(2)` and adding `cost.toFixed(2)`?

Why does multiplying it return `.5` and adding return `.50`?

Comment: toFixed returns a string. Your getCostTwo() function returns "11.50"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those functions return `1.5` and `"11.50"` respectively.  [Working JSBin Demo](https://jsbin.com/toveyig/edit?html,js,console)...

```
console.log(1 * '1.50');
console.log(1 + '1.50');
```

It looks like the string is cast in the first case (as though you had called `parseFloat('1.50')` and then concatted in the second. However, this is only the results ***on my own browser.***  Take a look at the official **[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Multiplication)**...

```
console.log('foo' * 2);
// expected output: NaN
```

So, Chrome is probably handling it well, but I wouldn't expect that kind of behavior across all browsers!

If you want them to both definitely return the right numbers, do all the mathematical logic first, and then format it with `toFixed()`.  That code would look like...

```
function getCostTwo() {
  var cost = 1.5;
  cost += 1;     // do the math logic FIRST!
  return cost.toFixed(2);   // once the number is just right, we format it!
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach. Thanks.